# How to enable radio group by checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I did search all over but i still cant fix it. Please help:

Here is my js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#email_acc").click(function() {
            if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
                $("#email_group").attr("enabled","enabled");
            }
        });  

        $("#system_acc").click(function() {
            if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
                $("#system_group").attr("enabled","enabled");
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

The following shows my html code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="email_acc" id="email_acc" />Email Account
<input type="checkbox" name="sys_acc" id="sys_acc" />System Account

<input type="radio" name="radio_email" value="create" class="email_group" id="radio_email_0" disabled="disabled"/>New
<input type="radio" name="radio_email" value="change" id="radio_email_1" disabled="disabled"/>Change
<input type="radio" name="radio_email" value="terminate" id="radio_email_2" disabled="disabled"\ />Termination

<input type="radio" name="radio_system" value="create" class="system_group" id="radio_system_0" disabled="disabled"/>New
<input type="radio" name="radio_system" value="change" id="radio_system_1" disabled="disabled" />Change
<input type="radio" name="radio_system" value="terminate" id="radio_system_2" disabled="disabled" />Termination
```

I donno what is the problem.It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `"enabled"` attribute or property, just a `"disabled"` attribute or property which can be set to `false` to enable the element(s) in question. (The "attribute" is in your source html, but dynamic changes are made to the "property", setting it to a boolean value to disable or not.)

Unless using an old version of jQuery, you should use the [`.prop()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prop) to update this property. To enable the whole group of radio buttons you have to select them all by their `name` attribute (or give them a common `class` and select by that).

```
$("#email_acc").click(function() { 
    if ( this.checked ) {  
        $('input[name="radio_email"]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});

// and the same for the other checkbox and group.
```

Note that your second checkbox has an `id="sys_acc"` but your JS is trying to select with `"#system_acc"` - you need to make sure they match.

If you need to disable the group again if the checkbox is unchecked then you can do the following, removing the `if` statement and setting the `disabled` property to the inverse of the `checked` property:

```
$('#email_acc').click(function() { 
    $('input[name="radio_email"]').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});

// and again the same idea for the other checkbox and group.
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UqTB3/

Note that in both cases I've used `this.checked` instead of `$(this).is(":checked")`: I find the former easier to read, and it is more efficient to check the DOM element's `checked` property directly than to create a jQuery object and use `.is(":checked")`. But if you're really keen on using jQuery for *everything* you can make the appropriate substitution.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

    $("#email_acc").click(function()
    { 
        if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) 
        {  
            $("input[name='radio_email']").removeAttr("disabled");
           //      ^----------------enable all the checkbox with common name
        }
    });  

    $("#sys_acc").click(function()
   //     ^---------corrected id
    {
        if ( $(this).is(":checked") )
        {   $("input[name='radio_system']").removeAttr("disabled");
       //         ^----------------enable all the checkbox with common name
        }
    }); 
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LuvaD/)

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/LuvaD/1/)

*Code updated for new requirements from OP, cleaned code thanks to nnnnnn*

## *UPDATED* [DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/LuvaD/3/)

Comment: In the demo the radio buttons don't go back when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: It works now!~This is awesome!~ Thank you very much ;D By the way, how to make it to disable the radio group when the checkbox is unchecked again?

Comment: @Derek OP question does not mention anything about that

Comment: @Sibu - But [his comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505747/how-to-enable-radio-group-by-checkbox/13505832#comment18486058_13505832) says he wants that too...

Comment: @Derek my mistake, i did not read that comment, i have updated my code though

Comment: When unchecked the check box, the radio button is still selected although it is disabled. how to make it to be cleared after the check box is unchecked?

Comment: Thank you very much. It's solved now... You've brighten my day!~ ;D

Comment: oops..im new here. sorry about that. i have another question very soon . hope you can help again :P

Comment: @Newbie select that answer which helped you most, and ask your new doubts in new question, someone will always help you

Comment: Newbie - If this answer helped more than mine select it instead - StackOverflow lets you change which answer is the accepted one. Note that although clearing the selection might seem neater it is not necessary since disabled form controls don't get submitted, and it could be argued that it's better not to clear it so that if the user checks the checkbox again they don't have to make a radio button selection again. @Sibu - your "Demo 3" uses a weird mix of `removeAttr()`, `attr()` and `prop()` - why not just use `.prop()` for everything?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#email_acc").click(function()
    {
        if ( $(this).is(":checked") )
        {
            $("#email_group").attr("disabled","false");
                  or
            $("#email_group").attr("disabled",false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add name in input html
2. name should be the same

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('cek3').onchange = function () {
          document.getElementById('fasilitas_kost1').disabled = !this.checked;
          document.getElementById('fasilitas_kost2').disabled = !this.checked;
          document.getElementById('fasilitas_kost3').disabled = !this.checked;
          document.getElementById('fasilitas_kost4').disabled = !this.checked;
          document.getElementById('fasilitas_kost5').disabled = !this.checked;
          document.getElementById('fasilitas_kost6').disabled = !this.checked;
          document.getElementById('fasilitas_kost7').disabled = !this.checked;
      };
   </script>
   ```