# Check box with radiobutton functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<style>
    .chb
    {
        width: 30px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".chb").each(function() {
        $(this).change(function() {
            $(".chb").attr('checked',false);
            $(this).attr('checked',true);
        });
    });
</script>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class ="chb"> I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked="checked" class="chb"> I have a car <br>
</form>
```

The above coding contains two check boxes with radio button functionality. This works fine. But how to do this with javascript without using the jquery. How to achieve this.

Comment: Why not just use radiobuttons?

Comment: Semantically you should be using radio buttons.

Comment: The client wants to use check box with radio button functionality without include jquery

Comment: it's back to document.getElementById but I'm not writing it out - I might burst into flames.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505747/how-to-enable-radio-group-by-checkbox/13505832#13505832

Comment: Jquery is javascript library, Nothing so much different in this... simplify your coding with jQuery this is best practice... chat with tamil   http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19992/tamil-front-end-developers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you concern only about functionality and you have lot of checkboxes this is an easy solution.

```
<script>
    function func(checkBox) {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
          if(inputs[j].type == "checkbox" && (inputs[j].className == "chb")){
             inputs[j].checked = false;
          }     
        }
        checkBox.checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

Now add `onclick` events to your all checkboxes as below.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class ="chb" onclick="func(this);"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked="checked" class="chb" onclick="func(this);"> I have a car <br>
```

Comment: i like the non-jquery approach (no pun intended )

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you only need this functionality for inputs with the class name `chb`. Otherwise even more loops will be required.

Unlike the other solutions mentioned here, my code doesn't require adding `onclick` to every checkbox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-CA">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> My page </title>
    <script>
    function doCrazyCheckRadioThing(v) {
        var checkboxes, i;

        for(i=0, checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chb'); i<checkboxes.length; i+=1) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = (checkboxes[i].value === v);
        }
    }

    function init() {
        var checkboxes, i;

        for(i=0, checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chb'); i<checkboxes.length; i+=1) {
            checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
                doCrazyCheckRadioThing(this.value);
            }, false);
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false); 
    </script>
<body>
    <form action="demo_form.asp">
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id='bike' value="Bike" class="chb"> I have a bike<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id='car' value="Car" checked="checked" class="chb"> I have a car <br>
    </form>
```

Again I must stress that is a **very non-semantical way** of coding HTML to do this.

Comment: But you are very correct. This is a very non-semantical way. I accept this point

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, you can have your cake and eat it too. If this is just about looks and you are open to consider a CSS solution, you can have radio buttons in the code, and make it look like they are checkbox.

```
input[type="radio"] {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    -moz-appearance: checkbox;
}​
```

No javascript or jQuery needed. However, I have not tested how cross-browser friendly this is. Definitely works on Chrome and Firefox. Definitely does NOT work on IE

Answer (score 2):

**Details:** Probably not the most elegant of code but it will do the trick and will give you ideas on how to customise it for your purpose

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkFirst" onclick="CheckboxCheck('first')" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chkSecond" onclick="CheckboxCheck('second')" />

<script>
    function CheckboxCheck(checkbox)
    {
        var firstCheckbox = document.getElementById('chkFirst');
        var secondCheckbox = document.getElementById('chkSecond');

        if (checkbox == "first")
        {
            if (secondCheckbox.checked && firstCheckbox.checked == true)
            {
                secondCheckbox.checked = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (firstCheckbox.checked && secondCheckbox.checked == true)
            {
                firstCheckbox.checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well @prageeth code works well and all but an optimization would be to just retrieve only the checkboxes in the very 1st line of code so that you would not have to check two things inside the loop, I guess this would save some performance time.

I even found a better way without even having to use any conditions inside the loop. This answer is edited..

```
<script>
    function func(checkBox) {
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox], [class=chb]");
        for(var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
             inputs[j].checked = false;
        }
        checkBox.checked = true;
    }
</script>
```